# Is norm of a differentiable function continuous?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, self-learning

The following argument is from my class notes. "Suppose $\gamma(s): I\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ is a regular curve. Fix $t_0$ and define $s(t) = \int_{t_0}^t \|\gamma'(t)\|dt$. That is, $s(t)$ is the length of the curve from $t_0$ to $t$. Then $s(t)$ is continuous." Why is $s(t)$ continuous, please?

My guess is that $\|\gamma'(t)\|$ is continuous and its integral is also continuous. Is this correct, please? if so, why is $\|\gamma'(t)\|$ continuous? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If put $M = \max |f'(t)|$ on $I = [0, 1]$, then you can show $|s(b) - s(a)| < M(b - a)$. From this you conclude $s(t)$ is continuous.

Comment: $s(b)-s(a)=\int_{t_0}^b \|\gamma'(t)\|dt-\int_{t_0}^a \|\gamma'(t)\|dt\leq [(b-t_0)-(a-t_0)]M=(b-a)M$.

Comment: @20824: yes and you can simplify the difference to a single integral from a to b.

Comment: Thanks, I am still wondering whether in general it is true that the norm of a differentiable funciton is continous?